# Time.deltaTime and Axis Input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine

I have a simple question. Say I want to move my character by translating it with a Vector2 velocity varibale which is going to get it's values from Input.GetAxis. When I write code as this:

```
Vector2 input=new Vector2(Input.GexAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical")); 

velocity.x=input.x* Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed; 
velocity.y+=gravityTime.deltaTime; 
transform.Translate(velocityTime.deltaTime);
```

I get a weird error in which my character barely moves at all (it moves but very slowly and it stutters a lot). However, upon removing Time.deltaTime from velocity.x I get it to work normally. I know what Time.deltaTime is and what it is used for however I am not sure why I cannot use it with input.x but can use it with gravity?

btw moveSpeed and gravity are just float variables with publicly assigned values.

Comment: Did you try to debug the code at all, e.g. by printing the actual values with `Debug.Log` or showing them on screen, and try to understand the issue based on that? The code you provided is malformed, by the way.

Comment: It looks an awful lot like there are some typos in your sample code (gravityTime.deltaTime? velocityTime.deltaTime?).  Beyond that, I would recommend looking at the units you are using.. Is moveSpeed  "world units per second if the user fully presses this input axis?" (judging by your code, it should be).

Comment: If `velocityTime.deltaTime` is supposed to be `velocity * Time.deltaTime`, then why are you multiplying `velocty.x` by `detaTime` twice? Plus, your `input.y` is not used at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve movement with simpler (but a larger quantity of) code.

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
{
        gameObject.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Simply repeat this for each direction and it will work.